# Stack Exchange Android app visually stuck on the achivements page

Tags: bug, android-app

Stack Exchange Android app has been visually stucked on the achievements page:

> [image: achivements]

"Main menu", "Inbox" and "Ask a new question" still working but central widget shows the Achivements page. Looks like visual and operable models have separated.

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-H860
- OS Version: 7.0 (172342203b663)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek if you mean whole app - yep I restarted it, now works fine. But I'm not sure that bug report describes expected behaviour :)